# Not defined error when using javascript objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Better explained with code, is there a way around this error? Im trying to simulate a namespace.

```
window.SomeNamespace = {
        Notification: Backbone.Model.extend(),
        Notifications: Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: SomeNamespace.Notification //error here. SomeNamespace is not defined
        }),
};
```

Comment: At the time you define the object, you cannot access itself. It does not exist yet.

Comment: On your second line `Backbone.Model.extend()` should probably just be `new Backbone.Model`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window.SomeNamespace` and thus the global `SomeNamespace` will not be defined until the right side of the `=` has been executed. So you'll have to split it into two parts.

```
window.SomeNamespace = {
        Notification: Backbone.Model.extend(),
};


window.SomeNamespace.Notifications = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: SomeNamespace.Notification
});
```

Of course you can do it in a nicer way by using the `extend()` method.

Comment: I thought Backbone.Collection.extend would be generic but apparently it isn't.. so the way i used is fine.